# Function over every column of list of dfs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dfs

```
df1 <- data.frame(name= c("mark", "peter", "lily"), col1= c(1,2,3),col2= c(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(name= c("mark", "liam", "peter"), col1= c(7,8,9),col2= c(1,2,3))
df3 <- data.frame(name= c("felix", "liam", "peter"), col1= c(3,5,8),col2= c(1,5,8))
df4 <- data.frame(name= c("felix", "lily", "liam"), col1= c(6,2,6),col2= c(4,2,2))

df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

I use this code for calculations on two consecutive dfs:
It matches the "rows" of two consecutive dfs by "name" and calcs a ratio of col1 between those. It then returns the results as a new column to the dfs.

```
df_combined <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by="name") %>%
  mutate(combined=(col1.x/col1.y)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(combined)) %>%
  select(name,combined)

add_match_column<-function(df){
  df %>% left_join(df_combined)
}

df_list_matched <- df_list %>%
  map(add_match_column)
```

Now I want to iterate over all other columns with the same function. Thus, col2 of two consecutive dfs in the next step and so on (my dfs have 100+ columns and all dfs have the same structure).

Comment: Firstly, it would help if you could briefly explain what your code does (at least for those not that familiar with `tidyverse` type of approaches that is) Secondly, your code appears to return `Error: unexpected symbol in: "add_match_column"` Think you must add `)` after `(col1.x/col1.y)`. But then, one is returned `Error in left_join(., dfy, by = "name") : object 'dfx' not found`

Comment: @Dion I have edited my questions concordant to your comment. Is it better now?

Comment: `R` is still complaining about the non-existance of `dfx` ;-) It should be one of {df1, ..., df4} OR you must provide additional information on `dfx`. And likewise for `dfy` and `df_list`.

Comment: @Dion yeah sorry for the mistakes, was in a rush. I think my code is just not working this way, as I try to this with a list of dfs but need to actually apply a function where df1 und df2 change to new dfs every iteration and the code also considers every column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you have panel data, where your observations for each period are in separate data frames. Now you want to calculate for individual `i` in period `t` the ratio between x_it and x_i(t-1).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# It is better to import all your df's into one list instead of separately assigning them
d <- list(
  data.frame(name= c("mark", "peter", "lily"), col1= c(1,2,3),col2= c(4,5,6)),
  data.frame(name= c("mark", "liam", "peter"), col1= c(7,8,9),col2= c(1,2,3)),
  data.frame(name= c("felix", "liam", "peter"), col1= c(3,5,8),col2= c(1,5,8)),
  data.frame(name= c("felix", "lily", "liam"), col1= c(6,2,6),col2= c(4,2,2))
  ) 

d |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "t") |> # Bind to one long df
  arrange(name, t) |>
  complete(name, t) |> # add implicit NA's
  group_by(name) |>
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x/lag(.x))) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  filter(!is.na(col1))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   name  t      col1  col2
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 felix 4     2      4   
#> 2 liam  3     0.625  2.5 
#> 3 liam  4     1.2    0.4 
#> 4 mark  2     7      0.25
#> 5 peter 2     4.5    0.6 
#> 6 peter 3     0.889  2.67
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>